# How to make React Router V4 routes work with React Transition Group (low-level API)

Tags: react-router-v4

After transitioning from React Router V3 to V4 I can no longer get the React Transition Group Low-level API to work. The documentation of React Router shows an example of the High level API with CSS animations which do not work with the Low level JS flavor.

Anyone managed or knows to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a month so I guess you found your way around, but it may help others.

I created this : https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-v4-transition after I encountered the same problem.

It provides a kind of transition-group in a switch component. Appart from changing your Switch to TransitionSwitch, it shouldn't require big changes.

I'm going to publish an update in the following days, probably Monday, that solves a little issue with the components implementing the lifecycle hooks.